Reduce trailing whitespace with flex-wrap and dynamic width children
On my site I have a list of tags that I'd like to display in a masonry-style layout, with clearly defined rows but no defined columns. This can be pretty easily achieved by: flex-wrap: wrap alone, as shown here:


 body {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background-color: lime;
}
.wrapper > div {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: .25rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>ipsum</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>sit</div>
  <div>amet</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>adipiscing</div>
  <div>elit</div>
  <div>Duis</div>
  <div>lobortis</div>
  <div>tempor</div>
  <div>mauris</div>
  <div>vitae</div>
  <div>ornare</div>
</div>



The problem that I'm running into is that there tends to be a gutter on the right margin, from where the row failed to fill. This would be fine for a row or two, but tends to be pretty consistent, with 1 row in a dozen being "full". Excuse the awful drawing, but here's my quick attempt at illustrating this:

As you can imagine, if you duplicate this image a couple times vertically, there's a really obvious gutter on the right side which creates an imbalance with the content that hugs the left margin, in contrast.
If I understand correctly, this is somewhat of a known issue, and something the CSS Masonry spec, if it ever progresses, will attempt to address, but is there any solution at the moment? Justifying per-row in some way, or an auto margin? Not sure, somewhat grasping at straws. Happy to switch to other methods if there's a better way than flex-wrap for achieving this, but everything I've seen of grid seems to be about well-defined columns and rows, which is precisely what I do not what.

The quickest way to achieve something barely resembling a masonry layout while using a flexbox layout is to allow its items to shrink and grow according to the remaining space where the next item cannot be accomodated.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex
Here the main change I made to your snippet was using:
flex: 1 1 auto;

The side effect is not having control on the item size in advance because it gets dynamic based on how much space is occupied by their minimum width. Any other solution would require to shuffle the order of the items to find most optimum way to organize them to fill the space.
To compensate that feature I styled the flex items so that their content is aligned to the center.


body {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background-color: lime;
  
  /*here you set the fixed padding*/
  padding: 1em 1em;
}

.wrapper > div {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
 
  /*here you allow flex items to shrink and grow*/
  /*shorthand for flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis*/
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
  
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>ipsum</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>sit</div>
  <div>amet</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>adipiscing</div>
  <div>elit</div>
  <div>Duis</div>
  <div>lobortis</div>
  <div>tempor</div>
  <div>mauris</div>
  <div>vitae</div>
  <div>ornare</div>
</div>



If instead you wished to keep the width of the flex items untouched, you may instruct the layout to use a dynamic gap to fill the remaining space in each row while keeping the first one and last one respectively at the beginning and the end of the row with justify-content
justify-content: space-between;



body {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background-color: lime;
  
  /*here you set the fixed padding*/
  padding: 1em 1em;
  
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper > div {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;      
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>ipsum</div>
  <div>dolor</div>
  <div>sit</div>
  <div>amet</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>adipiscing</div>
  <div>elit</div>
  <div>Duis</div>
  <div>lobortis</div>
  <div>tempor</div>
  <div>mauris</div>
  <div>vitae</div>
  <div>ornare</div>
</div>




Well that's embarrassing, I had thought of justify-content (even mentioned it in the post), but must've made a typo or added it to the wrong element accidentally, would've (largely) done what I had wanted! I had also wrongly assumed flex: 1 1 auto wouldn't work with the wrapping at all, but that looks great! Thanks so much for the help!
